# TabHost remove all content activities

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have a code for populating content for tabs dynamically. First time it works ok, but when I want to replace tabs (and their content) with new content - tabs are changed but tabs' contents are not, how can I clear completely whole TabHost and replace with other content?

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
Intent intent;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
tabHost.clearAllTabs();

int idx = 0;
for(Group g: c.getGroups())
{
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GroupActivity.class);

            ItemLookup.createForGroup(idx).putToIntent(intent);

            spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab"+idx)
                .setIndicator(g.getTitle())
                .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
            idx++;
 }
 tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in reusing same tab tags for new tabs.
I changed code for using random tab tags instead:

```
Random r = new Random();
...
spec = tabHost
.newTabSpec("tab"+r.nextInt())
    .setIndicator(g.getTitle())
    .setContent(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `clearAllTabs()` on the `TabHost`.